# How to work around Kusto's case sensitivity with JOIN

Tags: logging, analytics, azure-data-explorer

I'm building dynamic computer groups with Log Analytics (Kusto). I need to join two tables where Computer case sensitivity does not match. Has anyone figured out a workaround for this scenario?

Example (using one computer):

Heartbeat table has Computer with Name ABCDE.domain.com
Application_CL table has Computer with Name abcde.DOMAIN.com

If I run this query, the result set is empty, unless the FQDN's are an exact match. If this were SQL, it would return ABCDE.domain.com, which is what we need.

```
let H = Heartbeat | summarize by Computer; let A = Application_CL | where Name_s == "AppName" | summarize by Computer; H | join A on $left.Computer == $right.Computer | distinct Computer
```

I tried using =~ as the join operator, but it must be ==. toupper() and tolower() do me no good in this scenario.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the logic in your query allows you to use the case insensitive `in~()` or `!in~()` operators, you should choose that option.

Otherwise, you can extend a calculated column in both join legs before applying the join on that column (it's less efficient though, compared to if you didn't have to do this).

something like:

```
T1 
| extend lowercase_computer_name = tolower(ComputerName)
| join (T2 | extend lowercase_computer_name = tolower(ComputerName))
  on lowercase_computer_name
```

Comment: Appreciate that--but that would result in all lowercase FQDN's. Here's what I mean:

Comment: I can't have a computer group consisting of all lowercase FQDN's when the actual computer names (i.e. the computer name you see in the Heartbeat table) don't match. No queries for any kind of data using that computer group will return any results.

Comment: You're right, Yoni, someone in Log Analytics support came up with a very similar answer!

Comment: I needed to match values in columns where case is different, extending a column worked for me. But I do think Microsoft should add support for using =~ in additional contexts.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to do a case insensitive regex evaluation, you can include the case insensitiveness flag at the beginning of the regex pattern.

Like in the following example:

```
ServiceName matches regex "(?i)super duper express"
```

See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/re2
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/re2-library

Answer (score 0):

You can use Search instead, which by default is case insensitive